# Hypernym for being instantaneous or sustained

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

What is a word for the state of being instantaneous or sustained? For example, with *minimum* or *maximum*, a good choice might be [*bound*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34814/58563).

As far as the context goes, I'm working on adding some logging in to some software, and it'll keep an eye on certain statistics and see if they rise above or drop below certain thresholds.  One of the ways it'll be configurable is in whether each statistic will trigger a logging statement if its *current value* steps out of bounds *sustainably* ("Sustained"), whether its *average value* does so *sustainably* ("Sustained Average"), or whether its *current value* just does so *at all* ("Instantaneous").  So I'm thinking about what to call this configuration.

Comment: I edited your post in the assumption you are asking about a word encompassing the *state* of being either instantaneous or sustained; please feel free to rollback if I have misinterpreted the request.

Comment: You could say *instantaneous* and *sustained* represent the bounds of ***duration***. But I'm not convinced they really are "extremes", because in most contexts, *instantaneous* refers to how *quickly* something ***starts happening***, whereas *sustained* refers to how *long* it ***continues to happen*** (i.e. - the two concepts are somewhat "orthogonal"). A response can be either, neither, or both.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to define a level of *tolerance* for when outlying data points are logged. Logging whether the data goes out of bounds at all is zero-tolerance. Anything more than that means you're tolerating some level of outlying data without logging.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: following that, perhaps _momentary_ would be a better choice than _instantaneous_.  Or following IT jargon, _spike_.

Comment: This often known as *debouncing* a signal.  Where the signal must remain in the trigger range for a certain specified number of samples before the event is triggered. That count is called the debounce count or debounce threshold.  Note that a denounce count of one effectively eliminates the debounce filter and passes the value straight through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter Coad created a term "Moment-Interval" [to describe this phenomenon](http://www.step-10.com/SoftwareDesign/ModellingInColour/Moment-Interval.html):

> The Moment-Interval class archetype is one of four class archetypes in
>   Peter Coad's 'modeling in color' technique.
>
> Peter Coad defines a Moment-Interval class as modeling something that
>   one needs to work with and track for business and legal reasons,
>   something that occurs at a moment in time or over an interval of time.

In his later notes, he said he wanted to call it Transaction but the term was overloaded in software. But the business term of transaction can happen in an instance or over a period of time, so Business Transaction might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking at a rolling average or multiple measurements that exceed a threshold within a *time window* or perhaps a *sample window*.

The description sounds a bit wooly to my ears- maybe there is a more mathematical term that refers more precisely to the algorithm you are using, such as peak-to-RMS ratio within a sample window- or maybe that's too long for the intended purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest:

- *perseverance* with a human metaphor,
- *continuation* with a musical or textual one,
- *ephemerality* if the spike is an exception,
- *extensionality* in a weakening of the absolute philosophical property which spaces have and points do not, or
- *extendedness*/*extension* as a less haughty version of this last.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "**persistence**," as any hypernym for what you're describing would require further qualification.