# Umbrella term for maximum, minimum, median and average

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, mathematics

I'm looking for an umbrella term for the **maximum**, the **minimum**, the **median** and the **average** of a sequence of numbers.

For the **maximum** and the **minimum**, such a term would, for example, be the **extremum** ([Term for minimum or maximum](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34812/term-for-minimum-or-maximum)).

For the **median** and the **average**, one could use **measure of central tendency** (http://www.quickmba.com/stats/centralten/).

A very generic term for all four words would be just **measure**.

Is there a more specific term?

Comment: How about **statistics**?

Comment: ... and this would typically include **deviation** too.

Comment: These are examples of *set functions:* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_function

Comment: @jejorda2 My question is about sequences, not sets. Is there a corresponding term for sequences?

Comment: The maximum, minimum, median, average and deviation will be the same regardless of their sequence. The data might just as well be an unordered set.

Comment: @WeatherVane The median of the sequence (1,3,1,1,1,2,1) is different from the median of the set {1,2,3}. Sequences can contain the same number more than once, sets cannot. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence

Comment: @user55190 uh, **multiset** then.

Comment: @WeatherVane But the term "set function" is commonly only used with respect to sets, not multisets (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetFunction.html).

Comment: @user55190 it was not my suggestion to use terms for sets. I meant "set" in the non-mathematical sense - "bag".

Comment: The median of a collection of numbers is one of several averages which are all calculated differently, by _average_ do you mean _arthmetic mean_?

Comment: @BoldBen "The arithmetic mean of a set of values is the quantity commonly called 'the' mean or the average" (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticMean.html). I used _average_ in this sense.

Comment: @user55190 I tend to use 'average' for 'arithmetic mean' as well when it's free standing. I just found it a bit odd to have 'median' and 'average' in the same sentence when a median is a type of average.

Comment: In databases, the term aggregate function is used.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions you list are all examples of [aggregate functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function).

> Common aggregate functions include:
>
> - Average (i.e., arithmetic mean)
> - Count
> - Maximum
> - Median
> - Minimum
> - Mode
> - Range
> - Sum

Unlike [set functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_function), aggregate functions can work with multisets or sequences:

> Formally, an aggregate function takes input a set, a multiset (bag), or a list from some input domain I and outputs an element of an output domain O. The input and output domains may be the same, such as for SUM, or may be different, such as for COUNT.

The term *aggregate function* is more common in programming (especially databases) than in mathematics.

Answer (score 5):

Each one of these, max, min, mean, median, mode, variance, kurtosis, correlation coefficient, etc etc, and so on, is a

> [statistic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statistic).

a [function of a sample of data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistic).

Comment: This bypasses entirely the differences between set, multiset/bag, and sequence.

Comment: For specifically the four given by OP, I'd suggest furthermore ["summary statistics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summary_statistics).